Injecting a default value in Console.ReadLine
I have a console app (.NET 9 C#) that takes a few values from the user and processes them one input at a time.
Prompts:
Enter your Query: []{SELECT * FROM Product}
Narrow Query: [WHERE Product.Price > ] {10}
Narrow Query: [AND Product.Price < ] {90}

In the example above, the following should be assumed:

Each line is initiated with a sequence of Console.Write followed by Console.ReadLine.
Any braces (square or curly), are illustrations only (to explain the context). They will not be displayed during interaction.
All text up until and including the colon: is written to the console using Console.Write and cannot be edited by the user. This is when Console.ReadLine should ideally be called.
Any text within and including the curly braces is entered by the user.
Any text within square braces needs to be injected into the prompt somehow and be editable as if the user had typed it in before pressing the Enter key.

I have used the console In and Out streams before, but am not sure if they can be used in this scenario. Is there a way to call Console.ReadLine while providing a default value for the user to edit?
While I certainly do not want to use a mechanism such as System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys, I am open to an approach that does not require the console to have focus and uses a mechanism such as PostMessage using a known window handle (hWnd). Not sure if this is possible with a Console app. Upon searching, a lot of users have discouraged such approaches as being inherently unreliable.
Please note that this question is strictly about Console.ReadLine as I do not want to use other mechanisms such as Read, ReadKey(intercept), KeyAvailable, etc. Writing an input loop would be too cumbersome (dealing with ConsoleKeyInfo, etc.) for my purpose.
Any pointers to a reliable approach would be welcome.

Console.ReadLine does not support this. If "too cumbersome" is why you don't want to use ReadKey, how about using a library like this one (which uses ReadKey under the hood)?

@Sweeper: Thanks, and yes, ReadKey seems to be the only alternative other than external frameworks. I wanted to ensure that I did not miss any obvious implementations before resorting to the alternatives. Your comment is an acceptable answer as is.

Youll have to fudge it by printing the default with Write, backspacing to reposition the cursor, if the user starts typing then as soon as they hit a different key to what's next on the default, clear the rest of the line with spaces and backspace to where they use and let them carry on. It's quite a headache. Normally we take the easier/simpler approach of ("press return to accept the default XYZ or type your own custom thing" - if they press return and your ReadLine gets an empty string, sub in the default ...
